# Logistic regression with multi-class features in R

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, svm, multi-class

I'm working with a data set like the following:

*X* =

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 y
a  c  f  h  j  0
a  d  f  i  k  0
a  c  g  h  j  1
a  c  f  h  k  0
b  d  g  h  k  0
b  e  f  h  j  0
```

I'm trying to create a logistic regression model that is able to predict `y` (0 or 1) based on the features of *X*.

Info on *X*:
The values of `c1`–`c5` are all factors.
The features have a varying number of levels (e.g. `c1`: 2 levels, `c2`: 4 levels, `c3`: 3 levels, etc.)
Approx 10% of `y` is 1.

I've tried using SVM and GLM without any good result.

```
model <- svm(y ~ ., data = X)  
pred <- predict(model, X)   
table(pred,X$y)

        y
pred    FALSE TRUE
FALSE   1332   113
TRUE       0     0
```

and

```
model <- glm(y ~ ., family=binomial("logit"), data=X)  
pred <- predict(model, X, type="response")  
table(pred,X$y)  

pred                   FALSE TRUE
4.2260288377431e-08        2    0
4.24333100181876e-08       1    0
...
0.706714407238236          1    1
0.736650629322038          0    1
```

I'm used to working with features with continuous values when creating a predictive model, but I don't really know how to tackle a problem with factors.
What would you guys recommend for this type of problem? Changing from logistic regression to something else or using other functions besides GLM & SVM?

Comment: GLM has no problems with categorical features. It just replaces them with binary dummy variables. But you seem to struggle with the fact that logistic regression predicts probabilities of having a 1 (not 1/0).

Comment: Yes, I do know that. I need to set a threshold (e.g ifelse(val>0.5,1,0) ) for the case when I'm using GLM but it doesn't matter the threshold that I use, the prediction is still not accurate.
Could it be that my features are not good enough to make an accurate description of y? Or, what could be other models that I could try for this problem?

Comment: Are you sure your predictors aren't separating `y` perfectly? That's a problem for a lot of logistic multiple regression models.